# Alternative to Acronis Disk Director Advanced Server?

Tags: hard-disk

The Acronis Disk Director Advanced Server is a partition manager that can be used to manage partitions on a remote system. The client side component is called "agent" and the server component is called the "console". The console allows you to manage disks on several machines from one program window.

What other, alternative, commercial or free solutions are there for Windows or Linux environments?

Comment: Would local client+remote desktop be an acceptable solution? If not, what precise points do you want to be better than that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, EaseUS Partition Master (http://easeus.com) is a good choice and I believe the server edition allows remote management of disks.

I also sort of like AOMEI Partition Assistant however, its just a Visual Studio and sometimes causes my hard drive to get messed up, so I suppose you won't want that.

MiniTool Partition Wizard is also a good one.

I have a whole list here: http://alternativeto.net/software/acronis-disk-director-suite/

Not many of those support remote management but some do, but their prices are somewhat high. But yes, there's my list of alternatives.

Comment: I've had an older version of AOMEI corrupt my files when I used it to shrink a logical NTFS partition. I don't trust it at all. MiniTool Partition Wizard is the best I've seen so far.